# Grep -rl from a .txt list

Tags: bash, loops, unix, search, grep

I'm trying to locate a list of strings from a .txt file, the search target is a directory of multiple .csv (locating which .csv contain the string)

I already find how to do it manually:
`grep -rl doggo C:\dirofcsv\`
The next step is to to it from a list of hundreds of terms.

I tried `grep -rl -f list.txt C:\dirofcsv < print.txt` but I only have the last term printed.. I want to have the results lines by lines.

I'm missing something but I don't know where.
I'm working on windows with a term emulator.

EDIT: I've found how to list the terms from a file.Now I need to see which terms have which result like " doggo => file2, file4" did I need to write a loop ?

Thanks community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to pass the command as:

```sh
grep -rl -f list.txt C:\dirofcsv >> print.txt
```

Give it a shot. It should take all patterns from `list.txt` line by line and search in the directory `C:\dirofcsv` for files with matching patterns and print their names to `print.txt` file.

Try this for printing without a loop (just like you asked in comments ;-)

## One Line Answer

```
dir=C:\dirofcsv
listfile=list.txt

eval $(jq -Rsr 'split("\n") | map(select(length > 0)) | reduce .[] as $line ([]; . + ["echo \($line) :; grep -rl \($line) \($dir); echo"]) | (join("; "))' --arg dir "$dir" < "$listfile")
```

Another solution, for explanation say:

```
unset li
readarray li -u <"$listfile"
quoted_commands="$(jq -R 'reduce inputs as $line ([]; . + ["echo \($line) :; grep -rl \($line) \($dir); echo"]) | (join("; "))' \
    --arg dir $dir \
    <<< $(echo; printf "%s" "${li[@]}"))"
quoted_commands=${quoted_commands%\"}
commands=${quoted_commands#\"}
eval $commands
```

Breaking down the command for better explaination in comments:

```
# read contents of listfile in li
unset li && readarray li -u <"$listfile"

# add the content to new list so that it prints the list elements in new-lines
# also add a newline at top as it will be discarded by jq (in this case only)
list="$(echo; printf "%s" "${li[@]}";)"

# pass jq command
quoted_commands="$(jq -R 'reduce inputs as $line
        ([]; . + ["echo \($line) :; grep -rl \($line) \($dir); echo"])
        | (join("; "))' \
    --arg dir $dir <<< "$list")"
# the elements are read with reduce filter and converted to JSON Array of corresponding commands to execute
# the commands for all elements of list are joined with join filter

# trim quotes to execute commands properly
commands=$(sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<< "$quoted_commands")

# run commands
eval "$commands"
```

You may want to print the above variables. Take care to use quotes in echo/printf while doing so, i.e., `echo "$variable"`.

Replacement of `sed` command:

```
signgle_quoted=${quoted%\"}
commands=${signgle_quoted#\"}
echo "$commands"
```

I am now using the following implementations (though the dictionary implementation uses a `for` loop, the `key : value` implementation doesn't, and is a single line command):

```sh
# print an Associative bash array as a JSON dictionary
print_dict()
{
    declare -n ref
    ref=$1
    for k in $(echo "${!ref[@]}")
    do
        printf '{"name":"%s", "value":"%s"}\n' "$k" "${ref[$k]}"
    done | jq -s 'reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.name] = $i.value)'
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

# print the grep output in key : value format
function list_grep()
{
    local listfile=$1
    local dir=$2
    eval $(jq -Rsr 'split("\n") | map(select(length > 0)) | reduce .[] as $line ([]; . + ["echo \($line) :; grep -rl \($line) \($dir); echo"]) | (join("; "))' --arg dir "$dir" < "$listfile")
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

# print the grep output as JSON dictionary
function dict_grep()
{
    local listfile=$1
    local dir=$2
    eval declare -A Arr=\($(eval echo $(jq -Rrs 'split("\n") | map(select(length > 0)) | reduce .[] as $k ([]; . + ["[\($k)]=\\\"$(grep -rl \($k) tmp)\\\""]) | (join(" "))' --arg dir $dir < tmp/list.txt))\)
    print_dict Arr
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

# call:
list_grep $listfile $dir
dict_grep $listfile $dir
```

-*Himanshu*

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, error of sign on my description. But the result is the same, It only print the last line of the file..

Comment: Oh okay append `>>` should be there. sry

Comment: Thanks, it work on my term. But can't find how to write the query term before the results, I can't understand which result correspond to which query. Do you think that I need to write a loop for this?

Comment: Yeah the simplest implementation would be loops only, and since the program is also mapping many-to-many, loop is preferable. But you can try out with dictionaries and/or JSON using awk after you have got the output of grep say in a variable or in a pipe.

Comment: Solved ;). Upvote if u like. Accept solution if u think applicable. Sry if too hectic xD

Comment: Holy.. jq is truly amazing! Thank you for for your help mate, it work very well for me ^-^

Comment: Thanks mate. :-D... I spent whole yesterday in developing those commands. They aren't available anywhere.. With this first accept of mine, I just crossed 50 reputation points.

Comment: Just curious btw. Can accept and upvote both be done on SO? ;-)

Comment: Yes, you deserve it. You talk about the arrow on the side of your solution? I tapped it many times but stayed a zero, I'm new here don't understand alot about the options.

Comment: Thanks man. Your just saying this was more than enough :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -rl -f list.txt C:\dirofcsv >> print.txt
```

You are looking to append lines to the print.txt file and so will need to use >> as opposed to > which will overwrite what is already in the file.

To get the output listed in the output required in your edited requirement, you can use a loop redirected back into awk:

```
awk '/^FILE -/ { fil=$3; # When the output start with "FILE -" set fil to the third space delimited field
                 next # Skip to the next line
               } 
               { arr[fil][$0]="" # Set up a 2 dimensional array with the search term (fil) as the first index and the name of the file the second
               } 
           END { for (i in arr) { # Loop through the array
                                  printf "%s => ",i; First print the search term in the format required
                                  for (j in arr[i]) { 
                                                      printf "%s,",j # Print the file name followed by a comma
                                                    } 
                                  printf "\n" # Print a new line
                                 } 
                }' <<< "$(while read line # Read list.txt line by line
                          do 
                             echo "FILE - $line"; Echo a marker for identification in awk
                             grep -l "$line" C:\dirofcsv  ; # Grep for the line
                          done < list.txt)" >> print.txt
```

One liner:

```
awk '/^FILE -/ { fil=$3;next } { arr[fil][$0]="" } END { for (i in arr) { printf "%s => ",i;for (j in arr[i]) { printf "%s,",j } printf "\n" } }' <<< "$(while read line;do echo "FILE - $line";grep -l "$line"  C:\dirofcsv done < list.txt)" >> print.txt
```

Comment: Thanks you that's what I was looking for! Is it possible to print line by line? Like: doggo = file2 , file5 mouse = file4, file2. Because I have all the prints but don't who belong to which term.

Comment: Just remove the l flag from grep

Comment: It give me too much information, I need to keep the request line 1 with the files result, following to the request line 2 with the file results, etc..

Comment: To do that you will need to read each line of list.txt and then perform a grep with that line.

Comment: Ive added an additional solution for the loop

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, wasn't expecting so much!